# Is it possible to have one instance for all child classes?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have one parent class and several child classes.
I want to have a parent instance and have it instantiated according to a specific ID.
Child classes may have functions that are not in the parent class and I can't seem to have access to them.

```
class ParentInterface {
public:

   int gettemp();
};

class child1: public ParentInterface{
public:
    child1();
    virtual ~child1();
    int gettemp();  
    int getrand();

 };  

class child2: public ParentInterface{ 
public:
    child2();
    virtual ~child2();
    int gettemp();  

};
```

In the main I want to use it as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int id = 1;
    ParentInterface *c;

    if(id == 1) c = new child1();

    if(id == 2) c = new child2();

    cout << "print temp: " << c->gettemp() << endl;

    cout << "print rand: " << c->getrand() << endl;

}
```

I am unable to access the `getrand()` function from the first child. I know that c is declared as a parent but is there a way to work this around without having to add the `getrand()` function to the parent class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `dynamic_cast` to convert `c` as what it really is (a `child1`).

For example:

```
dynamic_cast<child1*>(c)->getrand();
```

And if it is not guaranteed that it is a `child1`, you'll need to check if the `dynamic_cast` has succeeded:

```
child1 * child = dynamic_cast<child1*>(c);
if(child != nullptr) // if it succeeded
{
    child->getrand();
}
```

But as ***@VTT*** noticed, your parent class is not polymorphic. To make it work, you must declare `gettemp()` as `virtual` in the parent class.
This will make your parent class polymorphic and so, when you'll call this method over a parent class which is in reality a child, the child method will be called instead.

---

**EDIT:**

By the way, your program is leaking memory. You always have to release the memory you've dynamically allocated (`new` --> `delete` / `new []` --> `delete []`).
Moreover, your `main()` function is supposed to return an `int` (usually zero if it ends normally).

Comment: `dynamic_cast` should not be and can not be (because parent class is not polymorphic) used here.

Comment: @VTT Oh right, I didn't read the code carefully enough, I'll add the notice in my answer.

Comment: If you know what the actual type is, you should use `static_cast`, to save on the overhead from dynamic_cast. NB! A static cast will not fail, if your object's actual type is not what you expect, and you will end up with undefined behavior

Comment: @Fareanor yeah I know I should add delete and return 0 for the main, this is just a small example of my code.